# Halting a Pester test already doomed to failure

Tags: powershell, pester

If a key Pester test fails, I would like to stop the execution of the remainder of the test script because I know, at that point, none of the remaining tests can possibly pass.

I'm looking for something analogous to Perl's Test::More `BAIL_OUT()` function. I've tried everything I can think of, including throwing an exception, but the script just marches on with every following test doomed to failure.

Comment: Can you post some  script demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented at this time. You can review the status of the request for the issue [Pester Issue 330](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/360).